# How to use gzip to pick somefiles and tell to decompress that in Python continuously?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to automate the below scnerio using Python:

```
    STEP 1 : In windows machine, I have 100 .gz files. I need to take first 10 files
    STEP 2 : Decompress those 10 files. output will be 10 .txt files
    STEP 3 : Now need to merge these 10 .txt files into one file
    STEP 4: Remove those 10 text files from that directory
    STEP 5: Now take another 10 .gz files (It should not pick .gz file that already picked in STEP-1)

Continue STEPS  from 2 to 4.
```

For this I have below script:

```
import gzip

file = '1.gz'

outfilename = 'test.txt'

inF = gzip.open(file, 'rb')
s = inF.read()
inF.close()


inF = gzip.open(file, 'rb')
outF = open(outfilename, 'wb')
outF.write( inF.read() )
inF.close()
outF.close()
```

The problem is, I am able to give only one input file (file = '1.gz').

If I try to give as , `file = ('1.gz','2.gz','3.gz')`. it throws below error:

```
"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found"
```

Could anyone help me to automate the above scnerio?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have provided a tuple of files, `('1.gz','2.gz','3.gz')`, `gzip.open` does not have any mechanism to load each file in the tuple automatically, you need to give it one file at a time.

You will have to iterate over each file name using a `for` loop.

If each file is named after a number, you can use `range` to generate the names

```
import gzip

for number in range(1, 101):
    filename = str(number) + '.gz'
    outfilename = str(number) + '.txt'

    inF = gzip.open(filename, 'rb')
    outF = open(outfilename, 'wb')
    outF.write(inF.read())
    outF.close()
    inF.close()
```

If each file name is different, you might want to import `os` and use `os.listdir`, or look into the `glob` module instead.

You can also replace the `f = open(); f.close()` pattern using the `with` statement:

```
with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as inF:
    data = inF.read()

with open(outfilename, 'wb') as outF:
    outF.write(data)
```